# Pay for Apple app once, install on more than one device

Tags: ios, itunes

If I purchase an app and install it on my iPad, can I then install the same app on my iPhone? Without purchasing it again?

Apple's app store is currently asking my customers to purchase the app (again) on their iPhones after I issued an update that supports both iPad and iPhone. The previous build supported only iPad.

Google searches keep sending me to "Family sharing" but that doesn't seem to apply in the case of two devices logged in with the same Apple ID.

(Apple developer support has not been helpful so far.)

Comment: Usually you can download and use an app on multiple devices that way.  I don't know whether adding a new device type to the app's capabilities changes that.

Comment: Did you change the Bundle Identifier? Did you submit the iPad+iPhone app as a new app or as a version update to your existing app?

Comment: It's a new build of the same app. The first build was just for iPad. The new build is for both iPad and iPhone.

Comment: The user can install it for free on any device that is using the same Apple ID for the App Store. If the user is prompted to "buy" then when they authorise payment they will see a second dialog that advises them that the app is being provided without charge as it has already been purchased.  They can also tap on their account icon at the top right, select "purchased" and "not on this iPhone" to confirm that the app will be available without charge.

Comment: Ask your users to open App Store app, in the Today tab, tap on top right, on account, In the account list, tap on Purchased, and search for your app. If it is listed, then it should just let your user to download the app.

Answer (score 1):

[Paulw11's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3418066/paulw11) comment was the best answer:

> For whatever reason, app buyers in this case are prompted to pay for the app (that they've already purchased on their iPad) when purchasing on their iPhone but if they continue through the process it ends up free as it should be.